# Only simulator crashes after core data migration

Tags: ios, core-data, ios-simulator, core-data-migration

I recently did a core data migration and I've followed the process before with no problems. This time however, the simulator was crashing after running the new migration, saying that it found nil when trying the access the `managedObjectContext`.

However if I:

-Run the app on my iOS device (which is already has the older version on it which is on the app store), I get no crash.

-Delete the older version off my iOS device, then run the new version via Xcode, I get no crash.

-Delete the app off the simulator and then run it, I get no crash.

Can I dismiss this as a simulator bug? I want to make sure that there is nothing wrong, because I'd hate to put out a new version of my app that's going to cause a lot of crashes.

Comment: I would suggest that you not dismiss it as a simulator bug.  It's likely that the simulator is helping you find a real bug in your application.  Please provide more context:  Sample code, the full crash report, etc.

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia I can't recreate the error because I deleted the app off the simulator, and that stopped the crashes. Basically, the crash was happening whenever I'd try to access my AppDelegate's managedObjectContext. The output was basically Xcode saying it found nil while unwrapping an optional value along with a bunch of text somewhat similar to a JSON document which contained the entity names of my data model

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia +1,000,000